# The password part of my Javascript validation check not working well

Tags: javascript, validation

I am compiling a full javascript form validation that will be reusable. It goes well until my password is checked against only one condition and not all.

Here's my code:

```
function validate() {

    //var emailID = document.myForm.EMail.value;
     //atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
     //dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
     var alphanumb = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
     var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
     var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;

     if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" || document.myForm.Name.value.trim()==null || document.myForm.Name.value.trim()=="" || document.myForm.Name.value===" ")
     {
        //alert( "Please provide your name!" );
        document.getElementById('p1').innerText = "* All fields are mandatory *";
        document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(!(document.myForm.Name.value.length >=3 && document.myForm.Name.value.length <= 20)) {
        document.getElementById('p1').innerText = "* Please enter 3 -20 letters *";
        document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(!(document.myForm.Name.value.match(alphaExp))) {
       document.getElementById('p1').innerText = "* Please only alphabets are allowed *";
        document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     <!----------------First Name Ends Here----------------->



     if( document.myForm.lastname.value == "" || document.myForm.lastname.value.trim()==null || document.myForm.lastname.value.trim()=="" || document.myForm.lastname.value===" ")
     {
        //alert( "Please provide your name!" );
        document.getElementById('p2').innerText = "* All fields are mandatory *";
        document.myForm.lastname.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(!(document.myForm.lastname.value.length >=3 &&   document.getElementById('p2').innerText = "* Please only alphabets are allowed *";
        document.myForm.lastname.focus() ;
        return false;
     }document.myForm.lastname.value.length <= 20)) {
        document.getElementById('p2').innerText = "* Please enter 3 -20 letters *";
        document.myForm.lastname.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(!(document.myForm.lastname.value.match(alphaExp))) {

     <!----------------Last Name Ends Here----------------->



     if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )
     {
        //alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.getElementById('p3').innerText = "* Please provide your Email! *";
        document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(!(document.myForm.EMail.value.match(emailExp)))
     {
        //alert("Please enter correct email ID")
        document.getElementById('p3').innerText = "* Please enter correct email ID *";
        document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     <!----------------Email Ends Here----------------->



     if( document.myForm.confirm_email.value !== document.myForm.EMail.value )
     {
        //alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.getElementById('p4').innerText = "* Emails does not match, pls check well *";
        document.myForm.confirm_email.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     <!----------------Email Confirm Ends Here----------------->



     if( document.myForm.Password.value == "" || document.myForm.Password.value.trim()==null || document.myForm.Password.value.trim()=="" || document.myForm.Password.value===" ")
     {
        document.getElementById('p5').innerText = "* Password cannot be empty or just empty spaces *";
        document.myForm.Password.focus() ;
        return false;
    }else if(!(document.getElementById('Password').value.match(alphanumb)))    {
     document.getElementById('p5').innerText = "* Please your entry must include numbers and alphabets *";
        document.myForm.Password.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(document.myForm.Password.value.length < 8 && document.myForm.Password.value.length > 30)
     {
        document.getElementById('p5').innerText = "* Password can only be from 8 - 30 letters *";
        document.myForm.Password.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     <!----------------Password Ends Here----------------->



     if( document.myForm.confirm_password.value !== document.myForm.Password.value )
     {
        //alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.getElementById('p6').innerText = "* Passwords does not match, pls check well *";
        document.myForm.confirm_password.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     <!----------------Confirm Password Ends Here----------------->


     if( document.myForm.Zip.value == "" ||
     isNaN( document.myForm.Zip.value ) ||
     document.myForm.Zip.value.length != 5 )
     {
        alert( "Please provide a zip in the format #####." );
        document.myForm.Zip.focus() ;
        return false;
     }

     if( document.myForm.Country.value == "-1" )
     {
        alert( "Please provide your country!" );
        return false;
     }

     return( true );
  }
```

```html
  <form action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
     <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">

        <tr>
           <td align="right">First Name</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Name" />
           <div id="p1"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Last Name</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="lastname" />
           <div id="p2"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Email</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="EMail" />
           <div id="p3"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Confirm Email</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="confirm_email" />
           <div id="p4"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Enter Password</td>
           <td><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
           <div id="p5"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Confirm Password</td>
           <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" />
           <div id="p6"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Zip Code</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Zip" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Country</td>
           <td>
              <select name="Country">
                 <option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>
                 <option value="1">USA</option>
                 <option value="2">UK</option>
                 <option value="3">INDIA</option>
              </select>
           </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right"></td>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>

     </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: I am new to using SO regularly & I am not very clear about the rules. Just curious to know why this question has been down voted. so that I will consider the points when I post my questions in future

Comment: Optimalresource,Please avoid using words like Name, Email, Password for field names. It may be keywords of JavaScript which will get into few more head aches

Comment: Your question states that the validation your code is doing is "not working well". In what way(s) is it not working well? What is the expected outcome for example inputs? Please add some more information like that. Also, looks like the start of your code did not get recognized as code the way you had entered it. You probably need to make sure that the first line of code is indented four spaces.

Comment: Thing is, I don't know how people downvote questions. I made it clear that other checks are working fine except some conditions in the password check. The first condition of the password checks well, but the other two fails, and somehow, it was downvoted. Please let the downvoter explain the reason for the downvote and secondly, I think I got some good ideas from your comments, thanks will implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `else` statements and using `return false` in them, which both prevent additional checks from being made.

Also, you're overriding the `innerText` of your error message output element so you'll need to make it additive with `+=` instead of `=` to allow it to append extra messages.

Consider using a variable to return at the end of your validation script instead of multiple `return false` statements. E.g.

```
 var return_flag = true;
 document.getElementById('p5').innerText = '';

 if( document.myForm.Password.value == "" || document.myForm.Password.value.trim()==null || document.myForm.Password.value.trim()=="" || document.myForm.Password.value===" ")
 {
    document.getElementById('p5').innerText += "* Password cannot be empty or just empty spaces *";
    document.myForm.Password.focus() ;
    return_flag = false;
}
if(!(document.getElementById('Password').value.match(alphanumb)))    {
 document.getElementById('p5').innerText += "* Please your entry must include numbers and alphabets *";
    document.myForm.Password.focus() ;
    return_flag = false;
 }
if(document.myForm.Password.value.length < 8 && document.myForm.Password.value.length > 30)
 {
    document.getElementById('p5').innerText += "* Password can only be from 8 - 30 letters *";
    document.myForm.Password.focus() ;
    return_flag = false;
 }

 ...

return return_flag;
```

Comment: I don't think using `return false` inside `else` condition will be a problem on all positive scenario

Comment: @ManivannanSadasivam "The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller." It will immediately stop evaluating the rest of the code as soon as it's told to return anything. In this case, it returns false to the onsubmit handler.

Comment: Drewby, the way he has written his logic, the program stops further execution on the first occurrence of an error & shows only that particular error. And he always used else if. So, it halts the execution only if there is an error

Comment: @ManivannanSadasivam "the program stops further execution on the first occurrence of an error & shows only that particular error" yes, which is what he's trying to avoid: "so far its going well until **my password check is only checking one condition and not the other conditions**". The reason it's only checking one condition is because of the return false statements and the `if else` chains.

Comment: Drewby, if this is the issue & if he is trying to avoid this issue then he might have faced the same issue during the Name validation itself. I like this little productive conversation but I am not sure if it's under SO rules.

Comment: I get what you are saying @drewby, but this same return statement was used in other else statements above the password delaration and it works like magic, so far, in the entire code, just the two else statements for the password fails. So i think Manivannan also has a strong point too. I'll review the code with our comments so far, and let us know what I detected.

Comment: Just checked, removing the return false statement continues the execution to the next if statement and return only the result of the first condition while overriding the conditions for the previous check. The return false is there for the sole reason of stopping the execution and focusing on the input field where the error was generated. I also appended the the innerText using the +=, no different result. Am gonna try some other options outside of what has been described here and get back to us.